# Are there an Asp.Net 4 web development tools for use on Android?

Tags: android, asp.net

All I can find in my searching is how to develop Android apps USING Asp.net 4. What I am looking for are tools or some sort of IDE (like Visual Studio for Windows, as an example) that are made to run on Android devices.

I don't want to develop for Android using Asp.net, I want to develop for web using Asp.net FROM an Android device. Since Google ignores such highly important articles like "from" and "for", I can't specify exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't develop projects for Asp.net which a Microsoft technology on a Android device

Comment: That makes no sense, you just need a program that can edit Asp.net applications with ease with pre-set codes and things. That's like saying you can't develop an application for Android on a Windows machine, in which case Eclipse wouldn't exist. I basically am working on a website in C#/Asp.net 4 and I want to be able to work on that when I'm  not on my computer and I want to work on it easier than hand typing lines and lines of code on a touch-screen keyboard...

Comment: no i was meant to say there is no back-end supply for developing .net applications on Android, you're right, in which case Eclipse didn't happen, but as far as i know there is no .net IDE at all on Android

Comment: Thank you, sorry if I was not clear. This is why the Google search is so hard: all I am looking for is an app that will run on android to develop Asp.net/C# websites, not that will develop ASP to run on Android, or to use Asp to develop for android, etc (because Google hates "unimportant" prepositions like 'of' and 'for' and 'by').

Since I couldn't search to find them, I thought maybe somebody would know, if nobody knows I am going to assume there isn't one. Thanks.

Comment: that's nothing, i'll let you know if I come across one :)

Comment: Thanks. I honestly thought there would be an app for on the go asp.net website stuff because so many people Constantly travel.

Comment: yes you're right, so I guess something might be developed in near future since lots of people travelling